# VB6 to VB.NET Visual Studio Upgrade Wizard hates some of my variable names

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb6-migration

I am upgrading a VB6 to VB.NET project using the upgrade wizard.  I know this is going to give me a lot of grief, but I am trying to make the old application useable. I'd rewrite it if I had time but am currently finishing up a summer internship and would like to get something working.

One thing the wizard is doing that I can find no justification for is renaming of random variables.  For example:

```
Structure ctrObj
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Index As Integer
    Dim Top As Integer
    'UPGRADE_NOTE: Left was upgraded to Left_Renamed. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="A9E4979A-37FA-4718-9994-97DD76ED70A7"'
    Dim Left_Renamed As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer
    Dim width As Integer
    Dim ScaleHeight As Integer
    Dim ScaleWidth As Integer
End Structure
```

For the life of me I don't understand why this is changing left.  It isn't a reserved name as far as I can tell, there is no other variable named left that I can find in scope, and renaming it does not create a compiler error.

```
'UPGRADE_NOTE: Left was upgraded to Left_Renamed. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="A9E4979A-37FA-4718-9994-97DD76ED70A7"'
    Dim Left_Renamed As Integer
```

changed to

```
Dim Left As Integer
```

does not give a compiler error.

It does this to seemingly random variables throughout my project.  Anyone have ideas as to why it doesn't like some of my variable names?

Comment: From the documentation: "In some cases, a variable has to be renamed because the original name conflicts with a reserved word. For example, a variable named Day will be renamed Day_Renamed; Day was not a reserved name in Visual Basic 6.0, but it is in Visual Basic 2008."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess is that it's renaming Left to avoid confusion with the VB Function Left.  This is a method on a module in a namespace which is default imported into every VB.Net project.  As such it is globally available.

For example:  This compiles just fine

```
Dim x = Left("here", 1)
```

It is probably worried that there could be an ambiguity error if the function was used without arguments.  For example

```
Public Structure S1
  Public Left As Integer
  Public Sub Method1()
    Dim x = Left
  End Sub
End Structure
```

However this can't happen though for a couple of reasons.  Primarily VB's name binding rules will prefer the member variable Left over the Module Function Left.

So, not entirely sure why but it's probably an over caution to avoid potential ambiguity.

Comment: Makes sense, though that's very annoying.  It is also doing this with a variable called logger-is there some default imported method called Logger?

Answer (score 1):

[Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y050k1wb.aspx) is a string function in Visual Basic.  It takes the specified number of characters from the left side of a string and returns a new string containing those characters.

Answer (score 1):

VB6  x$ = left$("hello world",5)
     print x$  hello

VB2005,8,9 vs VB6

```
 left = left$
 right = right$
 mid   = mid$
 trim  = trim$
 chr(13)+chr(10) = Chr$(32)+ Chr$(10) (line feed + carriage return)
```

left is a reserve word and will generate errors so the conversion program changes it in a way that you know it's been changed.